# Is this a closed form? If not, can it be recast as one?

Tags: function-construction

Is this a closed form? If not, can it be recast as one?

```
x[n_] := Module[{x}, (x = 1); While[0 < 3^n - 2^n (++x)]; --x]
```

It is looking for the greatest $x$ that calculates a positive number.

Comment: It looks like this sequence: https://oeis.org/A002379. It seems `x[n] == Floor[(3/2)^(n)]`. I am not sure if you can call that a closed form though, because of `Floor`.

Comment: @anderstood, I was trying to get that without the `Floor`.

Comment: without floor function `x[n] = -(1/2) + (3/2)^n + ArcTan[Cot[(3/2)^n π]]/π`

Comment: Glad you got an answer. As a side note, if your question is to write the floor function in a closed form, it probably rather belongs to math.SE.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Wow... Respect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
x[n_] := Module[{x}, (x = 1); While[0 < 3^n - 2^n (++x)]; --x]; 
Table[x[n], {n, 1, 20}]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 17, 25, 38, 57, 86, 129, 194, 291, 437, 656, 985, 1477, 2216, 3325}

As mentioned by [anderstood](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18767/anderstood) in the comment above, this integer [sequence](https://oeis.org/A002379) can by expressed by `Floor[(3/2)^(n)]` function.

The floor function can be expressed using the **formula**:

$\lfloor x\rfloor =x-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sin (2 k \pi  x)}{k}}{\pi }$

$=-1+\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \theta
   (x-k)$

$=-1+x+\text{SawtoothWave}[-x]$

$=x-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i \log \left(-e^{2 i \pi  x}\right)}{2 \pi }$

$=x-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\tan ^{-1}(\cot (\pi x))}{\pi }$

Mma code:

```
Floor[x] == 
x - 1/2 + 1/Pi*Sum[Sin[2*k*Pi*x]/k, {k, 1, Infinity}] ==
-1 + Sum[HeavisideTheta[x - k], {k, 0, Infinity}] ==
-1 + x + SawtoothWave[-x] ==
x - 1/2 + (I Log[-E^(2 I \[Pi] x)])/(2 \[Pi]) ==
x - 1/2 + ArcTan[Cot[Pi*x]]/Pi
```

Substituting to the last:

```
x - 1/2 + ArcTan[Cot[Pi*x]]/Pi /. x -> (3/2)^n

x[n_] := -(1/2) + (3/2)^n + ArcTan[Cot[(3/2)^n π]]/π

Table[x[n], {n, 1, 20}]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 17, 25, 38, 57, 86, 129, 194, 291, 437, 656, 985, 1477, 2216, 3325}

Comment: @FredKline. I got a nice gift for the Christmas tree. Thank You very much .Merry Christmas Fred Kline. :)

Comment: Cited by https://oeis.org/A297446

Comment: @FredKline. Nice suprise :)